# I need help for fixing my two functions

Tags: python, function

I am trying to implement a candidate-elimination algorithm in python. I need to write two functions , one for finding the more general hypotheses and one for finding the more specific hypotheses. 
Based on the definition, the more numbers of "question marks" and the less number of "zeros" mean more general and vice versa.
But my functions are not working. they only return false. where is the problem?

```
def more_specific(a, b):
    """
    Checks if a is more specific than b.
    """
    aa = 1
    bb = 1
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == '0':
           aa+=1
        elif a[i] == '?':
           aa-=1

    for k in range(len(b)):
        if b[k] == '0':
           bb+=1
        elif b[k] == '?':
           bb-=1


    return aa > bb


def more_general(a, b):
    """
       Checks if a is more general than b.
    """
    aa = 1
    bb = 1
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] == '?':
           aa+=1
        elif a[i] == '0':
           aa-=1

    for k in range(len(b)):
        if b[k] == '?':
           bb+=1
        elif b[k] == '0':
           bb-=1

    return aa > bb
```

Try with this examples:

```
a = [('far','?', '?', '?')]
b = [('ss' , '0','0','i')]
```

Comment: They work fine for me...

Comment: `more_specific('00', '??')` returns `True`.

Comment: did you change anything the code?

Comment: I have put the examples i am working with above

Answer (score 0):

Your data for `a` and `b` has the wrong format. Just remove the outside `[]`:

```
>>> a = ('far','?', '?', '?')
>>> b = ('ss' , '0','0','i')
>>> more_specific(b, a)
True
```

Your list has only one element that is a tuple:

```
>>> len([('far','?', '?', '?')])
1
```

But you want to go through all of the elements of the tuple:

```
>>> len(('far','?', '?', '?'))
4
```